# Under what conditions is the operator $Ax = [x, y]x'$ a projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space, $x'$ is a vector in $V$, and $y$ is a linear
functional on $V$; write $Ax = [x, y]x'$ for every $x \in V$. Under what conditions
on $x'$ and $y$ is $A$ a projection?

**Source**: Halmos, Finite dimensional vector spaces, section 43 projection exercise #2.

Below is what I think.

Since $A$ is a projection if and only if $A=A^2$.
Now $Ax = [x, y]x'=y(x)x'$, $A^2(x)=A(Ax)=A(y(x)x')=[y(x)x', y]x'$.
Hence, if $x=y(x)x'$, then $A$ is a projection.

Am I right? My solution seems too good to be true.

Please help, if that is not right, what's the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please put this in LaTeX.

Comment: Your formulas are incomprehensible. You never close your brackets `[`, and there seems to be something going on with lower case L `l`. But I cannot figure out what. One could guess $Ax=x.y_0(x_0)$ but that is just a scalar multiplication. Rather $Ax=\langle x,y_0\rangle x_0$ (which I would write $Ax=y_0(x)x_0$?

Comment: sorry AJY, i don't know how to do LaTex. I have changed the varibles to make the question easier to follow.

Comment: MarcvanLeeuwen, yes, thank you Marcvan.the lower case L is the right hand side closed bracket. sorry.. and I meant the senond case you point out. Ax=y0(x)x0. just the original question is [x,y0]x0, so i put that here.

Comment: For a first approximation to LaTeX formatting, just type a `$` before and after each complete formula. I've done it for you; if you click "edit" you can see how.

Comment: $Marcvan$, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and your condition $x=y(x)x'$ does not depend only on $A$, so it makes no sense. You should have $$A^2x=A(Ax)=A(y(x)x')=y(y(x)x')x'=y(x)y(x')x'=y(x')y(x)x'=y(x')Ax$$ so $A^2=A$ if an only if $y(x')=1$.

It is a bit more readable writing $Ax=x'.y(x)$ (so writing scalars to the right of vectors separated by a dot) so that by linearity of $A$
$$A^2x=A(x'.y(x))=A(x').y(x)=x'.y(x').y(x)=x'.y(x).y(x')=Ax.y(x').$$
Either way commutation of two scalar multiplications occurs (just for those wondering whether this can be done in general over skew fields; it cannot;-).